# Reload a transient page in .NET MAUI from within the page

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, navigation, maui

I have a .NET MAUI app with a page registered as transient in MauiProgram.cs. I want to be able to reset the page using a button on the page itself but do not know how. Please could someone help me.

I've already tried using this code, but it did not do anything:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task ReloadPageAsync()
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../"+nameof(MyPage), false);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Get current page
var page = Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

// Load new page
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SecondPage), false);

// Remove old page
Navigation.RemovePage(page);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Only thing is that I had to use `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();` to make it recognise the `Navigation` namespace - is this ok or is there a better way?

Comment: Sound fine to me  Another approach if you are using the MVVM pattern, would be to just recreate the view model and assign that to the BindingContext.

Comment: @PEK Hie there, I am using MVVM and by following your suggestion, the ViewModel isn't being instantiated. How do I fix this?

Comment: @TanakaMawere, how is the viewmodel instantied normally? In the constructor, DI, or something else?

Comment: Thanks. I registered the Viewmodel as a singleton with the DI. It is now working as expected