# Dependency Injection in .NET MAUI not refreshing page

Tags: c#, maui

I am converting my application to use dependency injection for decoupling. The following functionality was working prior to this change.
I have a TopicSelection Page which consists of a CollectionView with topics. A user can download or delete a topic. When a user presses download on a topic, it downloads and the CollectionView refreshes so as to show a "Downloaded" tag on the item template.
The reverse happens with delete. The "Downloaded" tag is invisible and changes with either download or delete.

The problem I am facing is that after using Dependency injection for the page and viewmodel, the Refresh method is being called but there are no changes on the UI. The collectionView is not refreshed hence if a user downloads a topic, the "Downloaded" tag doesn't appear and vice versa.

**TopicSelectionViewModel.cs**

```
public TopicSelectionViewModel(IApiService apiService, IDatabaseRepository _repo, LoadingControl popup)
        {
            ApiService = apiService;
            repository = _repo;
            loadingControl = popup;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        void Refresh()
        {
            Topics.Clear();
            try
            {
                if (courseSelected is not null)
                {
                    Title= courseSelected.Title;
                    ImageURL = courseSelected.ImageURL;

                    Topics.AddRange(repository.GetTopicsAsync(courseSelected.CourseRef).ToList());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
        [RelayCommand]
       async Task Download(Topic topic)
        {
            if (topic is null) return;

            if (ApiService.InternetAvailable())
            {
                try
                {
                    await repository.SaveTopicAndQuestionsAsync(await ApiService.GetQuestionsAsync(topic.TopicRef), topic.TopicRef);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Refresh();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("No Internet", "Connect to the internet to download", "Ok");
            }
        }
        [RelayCommand]
        async Task Delete(Topic topic)
        {
            if (topic is null) return;
            try
            {
                await repository.DeleteTopicAsync(topic);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Refresh(); 
            }
        }
```

I assumed that it is something to do with registering the page and viewModel as transients as below since I want to recreate the view whenever I need it.

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
//Other code omitted for brevity
        builder.Services.AddTransient<TopicSelectionPage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<TopicSelectionViewModel>();
```

Maybe another bit of information. If I navigate away from the page then come back, the UI is updated which makes sense because of recreation of the page.
How therefore can I get the UI (collectionView) to show its changes with Dependency Injection since the function was working without DI?

Comment: Have you debugged the code to verify everything in the VM is running as expected?

Comment: I do not know what is causing your problem. I know it is not the DI.

Comment: I'm giving it another go today to see if I didn't miss anything but I didn't change much in the vm from when it was working without DI to now. I'll update and edit the question as necessary

Comment: When you switched to DI, I woud expect some error when it tried to instantiate TopicSelectionViewModel. REASON: For DI to work ALL PARAMETER TYPES must ALSO be registered. Either that, or you ARE NOT actually doing DI. I say this because of this line: `public TopicSelectionViewModel(IApiService apiService, IDatabaseRepository _repo, LoadingControl popup)`. Do you call that constructor explicitly anywhere? If so, then you aren't doing DI. If not, then need to declare those parameter types with `builder.Services...`. Repeat for those types' parameter constructors, if any.

Comment: I am not calling the constructor explicitly anywhere. The parameter types are registered with the ```builder. Services...``` as transient for the database repo and singleton for the apiService

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct way to do it but it is working.
[Reload a transient page in .NET MAUI from within the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268515/reload-a-transient-page-in-net-maui-from-within-the-page)
Following what was done on that link, I refreshed the transient page through the following method.

```
        async void ResetPage()
        {
            // Get current page
            var page = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

            // Load new page
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(TopicSelectionPage), false);

            // Remove old page
            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(page);
        }
```

So that I don't receive a blank screen, ViewModel is injected as a singleton.

Comment: IMHO, that's a gross workaround. Its interesting to know; might be useful to someone, as a temporary workaround for certain Maui refresh bugs. But see my comment on question: the real problem is almost certainly some mistake in your attempt at DI.

Comment: I am brushing through the code tirelessly. What's confusing me more is how it works maybe once then it doesn't. Then 2 or 3 times in a row then it doesn't.

Comment: Even with this workaround, it doesn't always show correctly? That is strange. Can you go back to your original (not DI) version, see if it ever fails? Is this on Windows or an emulator or a mobile device? Try "Start without Debugging" menu item (attached debugger affects timing) - same?

Comment: With the workaround, it works fine. But as you said, it's a gross workaround. I don't like it either. So I am really trying to figure out why DI is causing this inconsistent behaviour. I will test on different devices and OS's. Thanks for the help